# how to checkout the index into the working directory. It failed with error:Reference 'refs/heads/master' not found

Tags: ios, libgit2

I want to use checkout in libgit2 to imitate the "git checkout", but it fails:

- I have read the [api document](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/checkout/git_checkout_index) and used both two methods to set the second parameter,
- I read the example of test_checkout, set the third parameter to `GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE_CREATE`
  but it didn't work yet.
- There is already a `HEAD` file in the .git folder.

How to solve this ???

Here is the result of the code:

```
2013-01-12 18:48:27.789 gitlib3[8661:907] git_repository_open ret:0 
2013-01-12 18:48:27.794 gitlib3[8661:907] get repository succeed.
2013-01-12 18:48:27.799 gitlib3[8661:907] count ret:1
2013-01-12 18:48:27.807 gitlib3[8661:907] git_checkout_index. ret:-9
2013-01-12 18:48:27.809 gitlib3[8661:907] err:Reference 'refs/heads/master' not found
```

And the code itself:

```
(IBAction)Checkout:(id)sender {
    int ret = -1;
    git_repository *repo = NULL;
    NSArray *str = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPath = [str objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *localPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"efg/.git"];
    ret = git_repository_open(&repo, [localPath UTF8String]);
    NSLog(@"git_repository_open ret:%d",ret);
    if(repo!=NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"get repository succeed.");
    }
    git_checkout_opts opts = GIT_CHECKOUT_OPTS_INIT;
    opts.checkout_strategy = GIT_CHECKOUT_SAFE_CREATE;

    /*git_index *index = NULL;
    git_repository_index(&index, repo);
    if((ret = git_index_entrycount(index)) > 0)
    {
        NSLog(@"count ret:%d", ret);
    }
    ret = git_checkout_index(repo, index, &opts);*/
    ret = git_checkout_index(repo, NULL, &opts);
    NSLog(@"git_checkout_index. ret:%d",ret);
    const git_error *err = giterr_last();
    if(err == NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"NULL");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"err:%s", err->message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned error code (see the **[errors.h header](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/include/git2/errors.h#L30)**) **-9** means `GIT_EORPHANEDHEAD` (The HEAD points at a reference which doesn't exists yet).

An orphaned `HEAD` is a perfectly valid state for a Git repository. This happens, for instance, just after a repository has been initialized. However, performing a `git_checkout_index()` from an new Git repository would be of little value, but shouldn't fail.

Indeed, Git doesn't fail

```
$ cd /tmp

$ mkdir so && cd so

$ git init .
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/OneAmongMany/AppData/Local/Temp/so/.git/

$ git checkout-index

$
```

I suspect this error may come from **[this line of code](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/src/checkout.c#L1176)**.

Provided you were indeed trying to checkout a new git repository, it would be better to create an issue in the **[libgit2 issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues)**. If that's not the case, please enhance your question to add some more background information.

### Update

The issue **[has been fixed](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/1236)** in libgit2 repository. Thanks for having reported it!

Comment: I got it. You are excellent, I learn a lot from you, thank for your efforts. :)